# In what situation might we raise a probability to a fractional power?

Tags: probability

Given the probability, $p$, the probability after $n$ times is $p^n$.

I'm been wondering about this for a while. My question is what meaning is there to $p^{n/m}$ for some $n$ and some $m$? Could someone provide an example of where it's used?

Comment: What do you mean "after N times"? Is that some experiment performed N times such as flipping N coins or rolling N dice?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: This question seems reasonably clear to me, even if the answer is "it has no meaning and we never use it"

Comment: @Silverfish "We never use it" *except* when weighting likelihoods or making corrections to p-values, among other things.

Comment: @whuber Do you want to post an answer listing some possibilities? (My comment was badly phrased sorry, I only meant the "even if" as to say, even if the answer were in the negative, it is an answerable rather than unanswerable question, and in that sense clear enough to keep.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it's p^(n/m) and not P(E) = m/N where E is some event, m the positive results (i.e rolling a 5 on a dice) and N is the number of tries.
n/m is the relative frequency which converges to the probability of some event.

p^(n/m) could mean the probability of some event raised to the frequency, p(E)^(n/m). Does this makes sense?